# Connecting to a share on a domain machine from a non-domain machine

Tags: domain, network-share

We have a domain controller server and a web server.  The web server is a member of the domain.  There are shares on both servers.

I can access the shares on both server from my office based machine which is a member of the domain.  From home (over VPN) I can access the shares on the domain controller - it prompts me for credentials.

However when trying to access the shares on the web server I just get "You do not have permission to access...".  It doesn't prompt for credentials and there seems to be no way to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command line to map a network drive and supply credentials there like so:

> net use drive_letter: \\HostName\ShareName /user:DomainName\UserName

[image]

Comment: System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one username, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

Comment: Then run: 'net use' and hit enter, then for each shared drive on the remote server type: 'net use drive-letter: /delete' and then retry the command from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a local account with same username and password on your home and web machines, and that account doesn't have have access to this share.

Comment: How come it works on one server but not the other?  The permissions don't seem to differ.  I had read somewhere that by having the same username/password would make it easier to access them.  So if I change my username and/or password that should resolve the issue?

Comment: The same username and password "trick" only works with local accounts. The domain controller ignores it that's why you have a different behaviour. If you change your password at home it will ask you to login on both servers.